# Convert FunctionMessage into ABI string using Nethereum

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nethereum, c#

I want to convert **FunctionMessage** objects into **ABI**. Is there any function in **Nethereum** library to do this work or should I do it using reflection ?

code example:

```
[Function("balanceOf", "uint256")]
public class BalanceOfFunc : FunctionMessage
{
    [Parameter("address", "owner")]
    public string Owner { get; set; }
}
```

want to get:

```
  {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "owner",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "name": "balanceOf",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function",
      "constant": true
    }
```

as a string.